# Delete a Firebase Cloud Function which failed with `Deploy Error: undefined`

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How can I delete a *Firebase Cloud Function* which deployed with `Deploy Error: undefined`?

---

#### Steps to reproduce my problem:

1) Create a new *Firebase* project

2) `$ firebase init` and setup functions

3) Paste the following code into `functions/index.js`

```
"use strict";
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

function aFunction() {
    return 'reports/posts';
}

function getCorruptTrigger() {
    return '/reports/posts/' + aFunction +'/createdAt'
}

exports.thisFnWillFailToDeploy = functions
    .database
    .ref(getCorruptTrigger())
    .onWrite(event => {});
```

4) `firebase deploy --only functions`

5) The function will fail to deploy as expected.

---

#### What I tried to delete the *Cloud Function*:

- Removing the function from the `index.js` and deploying does not delete the function, instead I get `functions[thisFnWillFailToDeploy]: Deploy Error: undefined`
- Deleting the *Cloud Function* in the *Google Cloud Console* does not delete the function. (I get a toast saying that the function will be deleted, but this is not the case. In the logs there is an Error with `"status":{"code":13}`)
- Creating an empty cloud function with the name `thisFnWillFailToDeploy` also results in `Deploy Error: undefined`

Comment: If you're seeing unexplained errors with your project, please contact troubleshooting support.  They are best equipped to help you. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: I'll write a bug report if nobody knows a solution. Don't want to waste a precious support ticket on that ;)

Comment: I suspect there is a problem with your project that isn't just some bug or mistake.  Try again with a new project to find out for sure.

Comment: Actually I did that. I encountered the problem in my project. The steps mentioned above are how I was able to reproduce the same situation in a brand new project. (As I am fairly inexperienced with the Google Cloud Console and Firebase Cloud Functions I was not sure if I am simply missing something. That is why I submitted the question here first)

Comment: I replicated your code (adding the missing parenthesis and the semicolon) and it deployed successfully, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function in your project is in a bad state.  Apparently, deploying a function with a malformed ref causes problems with that function that can't be reversed on your own.  That function will failed to deploy from the outset (not even having a chance to delete it yet).  After that, you can no longer update or delete the function.  You'll have to contact support to recover the function, if that's what you need.  You should still be able to update or delete other functions in that project.

I'm guessing it's because you have a typo in your function call that generated the name of the ref.  You're missing parens on the call to aFunction.  I imagine you meant for it to look like this:

```
function getCorruptTrigger() {
    return '/reports/posts/' + aFunction() +'/createdAt'
}
```

If you deploy that in a new project instead, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The missing parantheses are intentional. The point of the example was to create a situation where a function that was deployed with a bad trigger path / ref can not be deleted. I just didn't expect that it is intended that you can only correct these mistakes by contacting the support or creating a new project!